# How to pull data from excel or CSV using Talend Big Data tRESTClient API?

Tags: java, mongodb, talend, rest-client

I'm using Talend open studio for Big Data(ver 6.4.0) and pulling data from HP ALM using `tRESTClient` and inserted into mongoDB. Now my ALM is down & i want pull data from any files like excel, CSV etc instead of ALM.

Is it possible to pull data from excel or CSV using talend tRESTClient? If it is yes, How can i do that same as HP ALM api call with tRESTClient?

Answer (score 1):

tRestClient is designed to consume restful services, not to read CSV or even more Excel files.
So I think you have 2 choices:

1. replace tRestClient by tFileInputDelimited or tFileInputExcel to get
   records from the expected files and transform the records to the
   expected format to be able to continue to insert data into Mongo DB.
   In this case you have to change the existing job.
2. build a new service, to be called in place of the HP ALM service, in
   charge to read files using tFileInputDelimited or tFileInputExcel,
   transform the records to the same format as HP ALM service and send
   the response to the caller which then can insert data into Mongo DB.
   In this case you have to switch from one service to another you have
   to write.

Don't think you have other choice.

Hope this helps.
TRF